# How to debug implementations of math equations

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, scientific-computing

First off, I wasn't sure whether to post this question in CrossValidated or here, so if it's in the wrong place, please feel free to move this question.

I've been getting interested in a subset of machine learning called Bayesian Nonparametrics.
As part of my learning process, I'm also trying to implement various papers in the field.

One problem that I often run into is that the equations needed to compute the relevant probabilities tend to be very complicated and contain a lot of terms.
I often find that debugging these equations becomes very tiresome, because even if the equation is not implemented correctly, the program may still run, but give the wrong answer.

Furthermore, in many cases, there may not be official implementations or code of the paper available online, which means that I have nothing to check my answers with.

My question is: given some complicated equation or math expression to implement,

1. How do you approach translating the math into code?
2. In the case where there is a "silent" bug in the code, how to you debug your implementation errors?

Thanks a lot.  I tried to include some examples, but I think stackoverflow doesn't support mathjax.

Comment: I fear your question is so general -- translate maths into code -- that only very general, and so vague, answers can be given. For example: split the problem up into tiny bits and test the bits independently.

Comment: A divide and conquer approach as suggested by dmuir is a very good idea. In addition, take a look at representing your equations in a computer algebra system, so that you can inspect them to see if they match the book or article, and use that representation to verify that you get the expected outputs for specific inputs. From there one can generate code in a conventional programming language (e.g. C or Fortran, maybe others) which you can execute. I know Maxima (http://maxima.sourceforge.net) can do that, I'm guessing Sympy (https://sympy.org) or other systems can too.

Comment: Also, bear in mind that you will be working on the very cutting edge -- you might find errors or ambiguities in published material, so keep your eyes open! Finally, always try to work at as high a conceptual level as you can -- always state and solve problems in generality and avoid making assumptions, to the extent that you can, in order to simplify the problem. That approach will make it easier for future-you to comprehend what present-you was trying to do. Good luck and have fun, this is a very interesting and rewarding topic. PS. probably stats.stackexchange.com is more suitable these q's.